# How to store a tuple of tuples using Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a model `MyModelA` that uses `MyChoices` enumeration and I also have another model `MyModelB` that needs to do some work using stored integers. I know I can use six integer fields but I do not like the bulky approach. Is there a way to store the data in a single field?

```py
class MyChoices(models.IntegerChoices):
    OPTION_A = 1
    OPTION_B = 2
    OPTION_C = 3


class MyModelA(models.Model):
    # how do I rewrite this to look cooler?
    int_a = models.IntegerField(...)
    int_b = models.IntegerField(...)
    int_c = models.IntegerField(...)
    int_d = models.IntegerField(...)
    int_e = models.IntegerField(...)
    int_f = models.IntegerField(...)


class MyModelB(models.Model):
    choice = models.IntegerField(choices=MyChoices.choices)
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(MyModelA, ...)

    def what_i_want_to_do(self):
        if self.choice == MyChoices.OPTION_A:
            return self.model_a.int_a + self.model_a.int_b
        elif self.choice == MyChoices.OPTION_B:
            ...


print(MyModelB.objects.all().get(pk=1).what_i_want_to_do())
```

Comment: Please rewrite your question in terms of "MyModelA" etc instead of using first model/this model. Please also give an example entry and usage

Comment: @EhteshamSiddiqui done